# Plotting Generic Normalized Function in Terms of Normalization Variable

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a wavefunction with generic length `L`, without defining `L` as a particular length. The function is:

```
ψn[n_] := (630/L^9)^(1/2) x^2 (L - x)^2
```

and I want to plot

```
Plot[ψn[1], {x, x0, xf}]
```

where `x0 = 0` and `xf = L`. I am making `n` a constant, so only `x` and `L` are variable. However, the function is normalized, and all functions I will be using for this application will be normalized to L; that is, ψn is dependent on the ratio x/L.

When I define `L` to be any real number, my function plots fine, but the plot looks the same no matter the value `L` has. I want the axis to be in terms of L/4, L/2, 3L/4, etc. rather than some value I choose L to be, and I would greatly prefer that I never have to define L as 1 or some other value to get there.

I want a plot showing `ψn[0] = 0`, `ψn[L] = 0`, maximum at `L/2`, etc.

I am wondering if there is a way to plot this on a domain in terms of `L`.

Comment: If `L` is indeed generic, then setting `L` to `1` arbitrarily and changing the ticks to accommodate this should do the trick.

Comment: @J.M. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
ψ[L_][x_] := (630/L^9)^(1/2) x^2 (L - x)^2
```

Then

```
With[{L = 2}, Plot[ψ[L][x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"L = ", L}]]]
```

gives

[image: plot_1]

and

```
With[{L = 5}, Plot[ψ[L][x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"L = ", L}]]]
```

gives

[image: plot_2]

Comment: Thanks, I had already considered this, but seeing the 2 plots you made caused me to realize that the domain of the function changes, even while the function was normalized and the wave function probability (integral of function times it's complex conjugate) was always 1 no matter the function. I used a combination of what you showed here and the suggestion of @J. M. of changing the ticks with L set to 1 to get the plot that I wanted.